# Record audio with Ringdroid (or similar program) from another app

Tags: android, audio-recording

I have an app where I need the user to record their voice, and then come back to my application.  I would like to give the user the ability to adjust/edit and verify their audio before they get back to my app.  My app would need to be able to specify where to store the recorded audio either
   1) while launching the recorder (preferably) or  
   2) having access to the recorded audio when regaining execution.

This custom soundboard app: http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.onymous.soundboard/ seems to use Ringdroid for this purpose, although it only uses Ringdroid to record but not to edit (editing seems like the key feature for using Ringdroid, so I don't understand why).

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Alex